# Is there an order in which the leaders effect applies?

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-leaders

I know this is irrelevant in most of the cases because leader effects are independent or can be combined achieving the same effect, but I found a case in which the order matters.
We are playing with the [anniversary leaders pack](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/3836370/7-wonders-leaders-anniversary-pack) and let's say we got the following scenario.

Alice has played both Acanice (first row second column in the image above) and Eniheduanina (first row, third column).

- Acanice allows you to switch one of the science symbols, basically transforming one of the green symbols into a wildcard (similar to the guild).
- Eniheduanina gives you an extra science symbol where you have the most.

At the end of the game Alice has in front of her 5 science symbols like this:

- 1 gear (1g)
- 2 compasses (2c)
- 2 stones. (2s)

**Case 1**

Applying the effect of `Eniheduanina` first, will let Alice have the following configuration: 1g, 2c, 3s (or 1g, 3c, 2s - it's irrelevant).
Then applying the effect of `Acanice` will let Alice have 2 complete sets by changing one stone to a gear, scoring 26 points.

**Case 2**.
Applying the effect of `Acanice` first, Alice can get the max score by chaging one compass to a stone (or the other way around - again irrelevant).
Applying `Eniheduanina` effect will get Alice the the following configuration 1g, 1c, 4s (2s + 1c turned to s to 1 extra s).  This totals up to 25 points.

As you can see, switching the order of the leaders ends up in 2 different scores.

**Main question**
Is there an order in which the leaders effects are applied, or Alice can choose the order in such a way that her "profit" is maximized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the rulebooks specify an order to scoring the cards at the end of the game (leaders or otherwise), so it looks like Alice can apply them in whatever order she chooses.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, because it looks like a loophole, but it's something I can work with. Mainly because it answers my followup question "What happens if in the scenario above I replace Acanic" with a mask symbol from the black cards and I can can clone any green symbol from the neighbors?" Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say it's a loophole?  The game lets you make the best strategic choice.

Comment: @Joe. I didn't say it's a loophole. I said "it looks like a loophole" :). Maybe you are right. It's more of a "Non liquet"  than a loophole. I'm saying this because it is not written in the rules "You are allowed to do this and that". The answer was "there is nothing in the rulebook that prohibits this". Anyway. I'm cool with it. I will point to this answer the next time this case happens in one of our games.